# NSIS: How to add Items to a listbox control?

Tags: listbox, runtime, nsis, listboxitem

How to add items to a listbox control at run time in NSIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey I got that:

```
GetDlgItem $1 $HWND 1200
SendMessage $1 ${LB_ADDSTRING} 1 "STR:$R2"
```

where R2 contains the string I want to add to my list box.
Ok now can anyone help me with a code to read a file line-by-line till EOF and display this file line-by-line in the listbox. Also the file that I am reading here contains list of filenames and depending upon user selection of listitem from the listbox I want to delete that particular file.

Answer (score 0):

FileRead reads one line at the time (See the [docs](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.9.5) for a complete example)

Comment: Yes but FileRead reads a line alongwith $\r$\n hence when I read this line and display it in my listbox I get some garbage characters after the line which I certainly dont want...I just want to display the line as it is...